# IdentityServer 4 with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, identityserver4

Would like to know if I can use Active Directory for authentication and IdentityServer 4 for authorization.  Was thinking if IdentityServer 4 can somehow use the identity tokens issued from AD and then it would issue it's own access tokens.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/windows.html

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-active-directory-ad-as-the-repository-for-authentication-with-identityserver4-fa010e0980db

Answer (score 1):

please check:https://github.com/jusbuc2k/Justin.AspNetCore.LdapAuthentication
it works for me